# How does vivaldi.net set URL bar color in Chrome for Android?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I mean that effect. You can check it on your own by navigating to http://vivaldi.net with Chrome on Android.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android):

> Starting in version 39 of Chrome for Android on Lollipop, you’ll now
>   be able to use the theme-color meta tag to set the toolbar color—this
>   means no more Seattle gray toolbars! The syntax is pretty simple: add
>   a meta tag to your page’s `<head>` with the `name="theme-color"`, and set
>   the `content` to any valid CSS color.

For example:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
```